# How to deal a specific amount of damage using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a datapack where if you touch lime glass, you get damaged 2.5 hearts. I don't want the commands to work for just this specific value. Instead, I want to be able to specify the amount of damage. I can't use the instant damage effect because it's not controllable.

Comment: I am working on something that should be done either today or tomorrow. It requires a data pack for ease of use and for multiplayer friendliness although is not required. Would a data pack work?

Comment: yes datapack would work

Comment: you finish the datapack? if you finished send a link or something

Comment: sorry, I ran into a few bugs when transferring it to a function, and all I have to do is make it more multiplayer friendly.  It also currently doesn’t work with any attribute modifiers.  If you don’t want multiplayer friendliness or to use it with attribute modifiers, then I could give it to you soon.  FYI, my damaging system takes 3 ticks to run.  It isn’t instant, but should be instant enough.

Comment: OK I will wait and it istant enough for me

Comment: if it will take more than a week from now send me now

Comment: did you finish?

Comment: The datapack is not 100% done.  But I will still give you the datapack.  It is 100% multiplayer friendly.  It’s going to take some time to write up an answer, and explain the datapack, so you should have the datapack soon.  There are a few things that the datapack isn’t compatible with that I will add compatibility to later and update the datapack.  Currently you can think of the datapack in beta.

Comment: I have finally finished it and posted the answer!  Sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1.16+

**Note: This data pack is in beta, and is in the works.  If you have any bugs please let me know, and I'll add it to the known bugs list.  Also, this is not tested in any version other then 1.16.4**

I created a data pack that allows you to set health and  deal damage to a player(for mobs use data modify instead).  First off, you can get the data pack [here](https://github.com/randomuser922/player-health-editor-minecraft).  After installing it, make sure it says in chat that it was installed.

## How To Use

**Dealing Damage**

To damage a player, set that player's `damage` scoreboard to how much damage you want to apply(negatives heal players), then run the function `editor:deal_damage` as the player you want to damage and you are done.

**Setting Health**

To set the health of a player, set that player's `sethealth` scoreboard to what health you want that player to have, then run the function `editor:set_health` as the player you want to edit health and you are done.

**Remember: 1 heart is 2 HP, and a half a heart is 1 HP, default max health is 20 HP(10 hearts)**

**The Commands**

To damage players:

```
scoreboard players set <selector> damage <value>
execute as <selector> run function editor:deal_damage
```

To set player health:

```
scoreboard players set <selector> sethealth <value>
execute as <selector> run function editor:set_health
```

## How It Works

What the data pack does is set the max health of the player to what health you want to set, and gives the player the instant health effect so it will update the player health, setting the player's health to max, then it sets the max health to be what it originally was.

## Known Bugs

- A bug that shows the player as dead, even though they are not. (Its a Minecraft bug)
- A bug that ignores absorption hearts, and skips to the base hearts.

## Incompatibilities

**All Incompatibilities are being worked on to be compatible**

- An existing helmet/item in the helmet slot with the max health attribute

## Finding Bugs/Issues

**Bugs**

If you find any bugs, please report it.  Also add how you found the bug, so I can recreate it, and fix it, videos/screenshots of bugs are preferred.

**Issues**

If you have any performance issues while running the data pack, please report it.  Also add what performance issues you are getting, low tps, low fps, etc.  Videos/screenshots and computer specs do help!

**Where to report**

To report bugs/issues, use either comments on this answer, or the issues page on the GitHub download link.

## Terms of Use

If you use this in a data pack to publish, I would like for you to put the GitHub link to the data pack somewhere for others who may want it, Thanks.  You are welcome to edit the data pack to whatever you want, just don't break it! :)

Comment: I don't know how to send a private message to you so I do here
I want to take the datapack for my datapack and of course, I want to give you big credit so what to write or link how to call you

Comment: @panda you can just add either at the download link for your data pack or in a `tellraw` command on reload the following.  `Some of this data pack was made using randomuser922's <link around here>health editor<put a link around here>` add a link to my data pack download.

Comment: Ok I will also write your name (randomuser922) and "Made the damage system"

Comment: @panda I gave a suggestion for what to do, and don't forget to link the download page.

Comment: I know I will do it

Answer (score 3):

use the wither effect for a specific amount of time to lower ones health controllably, as it lowers players health by .5 hp per second, or 1 heart every 4 seconds. Wither II drains one heart every two seconds, or 1 hp per second, which is most likely what you would want.
this command will drain the player of 2.5 hearts:
`/effect give @p minecraft:wither 5 2`

sources:
[Commands/Effect](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/effect)
[Wither (status effect)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither_(status_effect))

Comment: but with this the player "need to wait"

Comment: there's no way to directly deal damage to the player, other than instant damage,which they specifically mention that they *don't* want to use

Comment: i don't want to use instant damage because I can't fully control the damage that it will deal

Comment: Actually you can deal a specific amount of damage to a player.  I'm working on something right now that does this.  I'm not finished but it will be done soon.