# How to do less damage than instant damage effect with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So no one knows how to deal damage without instant damage effect, but how can I use it but deal less damage? Instant damage 1 is still way too much damage so how do I use command blocks to do less?

Comment: You've already posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/378499/250180); why would you need to create another one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal a specific amount of damage using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378696/how-to-deal-a-specific-amount-of-damage-using-commands)